# Python: Find Prime Number Algorithm

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

Recently I was given a challenge to my coding skills by my teacher since he saw that I was already knowledgeable in what he was teaching. The question is as follows.

*Create a program that prompts the user for 2 numbers. The program will then display all the prime numbers in between the two given numbers, including the given numbers. Note: You cannot assume the first input is bigger than the second input.*

So I took this question and built a fairly simple algorithm and ran it and it worked. I opened it today to find out for some reason my output is occasionally wrong, for example when you input 8 and 29 I get 27. I am looking for **HINTS** as to what is wrong with my logic because I cannot for the life of me figure out what Im doing wrong. I dont want straight up fixes because I would like to learn as much from this and doing it as much as possible by myself.

```
numbers = [int(input("First Number")), int(input("Second Number"))]
numbers.sort()

numList = []
#Removing Even Numbers
for num in range(numbers[0],numbers[1] + 1):
    if num % 2 != 0:
        numList.append(num)

#Checking For Prime Numbers
for currNum in numList:
   #Set Start number to divide
    i = 2
    while i < currNum:
        #Checks if the currNum can be divisble by i and is a whole number
        if currNum % i != 0:
          i = i + 1
        else :
          numList.remove(currNum)
          break

print(numList)
```

From what I have learned from testing this out it seems like 27 is never checked during my for loop or while loop even though it is in the numList array.

Comment: I wish they taught automated testing in schools. Look into [**`doctest`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html)

Comment: Your for loop never actually iterates so that `currNum == 27`

Comment: Never remove items from a list, you are iterating over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never remove items form a list you are iterating over.
Instead create a new list:

```
numbers = [int(input("First Number")), int(input("Second Number"))]
numbers.sort()

primes = []
for num in range(numbers[0], numbers[1] + 1):
    #Set Start number to divide
    i = 2
    while i < num:
        #Checks if the currNum can be divisble by i and is a whole number
        if num % i == 0:
            break
        i += 1
    else:
        primes.append(num)

print(primes)
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me understand what was wrong. May I ask why removing from a list is causing problems? I really want to understand what was wrong as much as possible so I can learn from it.